# Composing the Identity Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $T = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $S$ be the set of all permutations of $T$. Prove that $I\circ f = f$ and $f \circ I = f$ for all $f \in S$.

$I \circ f = I(f(t))$, so $I(f(1)) = f(1), I(f(2)) = f(2), I(f(3)) = f(3)$, so $I \circ f = f(1)f(2)f(3)$ which defines every element in $S$. Since $S = \{f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5, f_6\} = f$, where $f_i$ is a bijective function, $I \circ f = f$.

Something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right ideas. Here's an alternate way to phrase them:

Let $f \in S$, and let $t \in T$. Then,
\begin{align}
(I \circ f)(t) &= I(f(t))  \\
&= f(t) \ \textrm{ since } f(t) \in T\\
&= f(I(t)) \\
&= (f \circ I)(t) \textrm{.}
\end{align}

Thus, $I \circ f = f = f \circ I$.